# where to find jQuery or CoffeeScript tutorials?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

in rails 3.0 was working:

```
$("a.delete_link").bind("ajax:success", function() {
$(this).closest("tr").fadeOut();
});
```

Where to find information how to make it work this on rails 3.1 jquery script to work under .js.coffee or need to make new file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert this to CoffeeScript? Decent intro [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/rocking-out-with-coffeescript/) or at the [official site](http://coffeescript.org/). Not sure of any more in depth, free tutorials.

As far as jQuery tutorials, you really can't beat [Jeffrey Way's course](http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/).

For what it's worth, what you have would be

```
$("a.delete_link").on "ajax:success", ->
   $(@).closest("tr").fadeOut()
```

Use 'on' directly instead of calling 'bind', but I'm not sure what "ajax:success" is. Possibly a custom callback function? There is an ajaxSucess() jQuery function, but not quite clear on what you're trying to do.